# How to force save in hibernate when the entity has not changed

Tags: hibernate

I'm trying to read existing data and save it.
I have registered for the EventType.PRE_UPDATE event which encrypts few fields and saves.

I have a similar logic to encrypt when a row is inserted using EventType.PRE_INSERT call back, which works fine.

However the update does not work ( I suspect this because no field in the entity has changed). Is there a way I can force this saving even if the entity has not changed as a workaround?

Thanks
Priya

Comment: PRE_UPDATE method call  only  after a change.

Comment: Actually we are relying on the listeners. We and handling only encryption/decryption in our component. On PRE_LOAD we are decrypting and on PRE_INSERT we are encrypting. This works good. But the problem is with PRE_UPDATE. Is there any way I can force this event or any dirty bit to be set kind of a thing. Im not well versed with hibernate

Comment: how about adding some timestamp (like updateat)?